Why is my variable name not visible inside a dynamically created class in Python?
I'm trying to create a function that dynamically generates a class with a specified set of mixins and attributes. Here's a simplified version of my code:
def post_type_factory(name, singular_name, mixins, **kwargs):

    # Dynamically create a class with the specified mixins
    class PostType(*mixins):
        name = name
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            for amixin in mixins:
                amixin.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    return PostType

However, when I run this code, I get an error: NameError: name 'name' is not defined.
I want PostType to inherit from the classes specified in mixins and have a name attribute set to the name argument passed to post_type_factory.
Can anyone explain why the name variable isn't visible in the class definition and suggest how to fix this?

The class body executes before the function is run. Thus name is not in the scope of the class body. See here for more details: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax
A fix is thus:
def post_type_factory(name, singular_name, mixins, **kwargs):
    # Dynamically create a class with the specified mixins
    class PostType(*mixins):
    
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            for amixin in mixins:
                amixin.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.name = name

    return PostType(**kwargs)

A note on inheritance:
When calling the __init__ function you should not forget to provide self.
Thus:
def post_type_factory(name, singular_name, mixins, **kwargs):
    # Dynamically create a class with the specified mixins
    class PostType(*mixins):
    
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            for amixin in mixins:
                amixin.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.name = name

    return PostType(**kwargs)

What is more, using super(), you can automatically call all mixin constructors.
Thus:
def post_type_factory(name, singular_name, mixins, **kwargs):
    # Dynamically create a class with the specified mixins
    class PostType(*mixins):
    
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.name = name

    return PostType(**kwargs)


Thanks for pointing out the self typo as well. I wanted name to be a class member field and not per instance. I could do PostType.name = name after the class is declared, I guess.
